# How safe are Libsodium Crypto Boxes?

Tags: libsodium

I am currently working on a huge PHP project and we are seriously considering to use the Libsodium PHP library in it.

My question is related to the "sodium crypto box" functionality. We would use this functionality to implement *public key authenticated encryption*. We would generate keypairs using the "sodium crypto box keypair" function, nonces using the "sodium crypto box noncebytes" function, and seal/open the crypto boxes through the "sodium crypto box" and "sodium crypto box open" functions.

My question is basically "how safe is this"?

Public keys will be public, so our concern is that someone might be able to generate a correctly sealed box by "cracking" somehow the secret key of the sender, or to open a sealed box by cracking the SK of the receiver. These keys are 64-digit hexadecimal strings. Is my assumption correct that this means that there are 16^64?

If yes, this would mean that brute forcing all possible combinations at a rate of 1 million tries per second would take 3.6717430630808 * 10^63 years? Or are there more "efficient" attacks?

On the official Libsodium website I found the following algorithm details with respect to the functions we want to use:

> Key exchange: X25519
>   Encryption: XSalsa20 stream cipher
>   Authentication: Poly1305 MAC

Can someone try to explain me what this means ? Is following interpretation correct:

- X25519: This is the keypair generation algorithm?
- XSalsa20: This is the encryption algorithm?
- Poly1305: This is the nonce generation algorithm?

Comment: XSalsa20 is the encryption, Poly1305 ensures the encrypted data is not modified and x25519 is a public key system to secure the session keys (for the other two primitives)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can think of crypto_box_curve25519xsalsa20poly1305 as some composition of X25519, a key agreement scheme; XSalsa20, a symmetric-key stream cipher; and Poly1305, a one-time polynomial evaluation message authentication code.  But that's not the best way to think about it when you're engineering something out of it—partly because there are many ways you *could* compose those, but mainly because it doesn't help you to figure out how it fits into your application.

Instead, you should think of it as a **contract**, with obligations on your part and security services on the part of crypto_box_curve25519xsalsa20poly1305:

1. **Your obligations to crypto_box_curve25519xsalsa20poly1305.**

   (a) You must generate a secret key uniformly at random.

   (b) You must choose a distinct nonce for every public key and message you use that secret key with.  You may generate them uniformly at random if you like.
2. **Security provided by crypto_box_curve25519xsalsa20poly1305**, even in the face of an adversary who can intercept every box on the wire and persuade the legitimate users to create boxes for arbitrary messages of their choice adaptively.

   (a) Anyone who does not know one of the two secrets keys for a sender and receiver cannot open boxes whose contents did not already know.

   (b) Anyone who does not know one of the two secret keys for a sender and receiver cannot forge a box not created by the sender or receiver.

crypto_box_curve25519xsalsa20poly1305 does *not* provide third-party verifiability, also known in some circles as nonrepudiation: if Alice sends a box to Bob, Bob can't *cryptographically* persuade Charlie that Alice sent him that message without *also* demonstrating to Charlie the ability to forge Alice$\rightarrow$Bob messages.

This is spelled out in slightly more academic detail in the [NaCl crypto_box documentation](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/box.html) under ‘Security model’.

**Attack costs.**
crypto_box_curve25519xsalsa20poly1305 is designed to target a ‘128-bit security level’, which means that the area*time cost—area on a silicon die times amount of time you spend powering it—of the best known attacks is around that of $2^{128}$ bit operations, which is more than we can imagine anyone ever carrying out.

The secret keys of crypto_box_curve25519xsalsa20poly1305 are indeed 256 bits long, but there is enough mathematical structure in X25519 to admit an attack cheaper than simply enumerating and trying all possible secret keys—so much cheaper that the best you can hope to get for an elliptic curve over a field of 256 bits is a 128-bit security level.  You can find highly technical references about these attacks at [SafeCurves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/) under ‘ECDLP security’.

The secret keys of *crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305*, an operation out of which crypto_box_curve25519xsalsa20poly1305 is built, are also 256 bits long, but the nature of the kind of object that a secretbox is allows *multi-target* attacks, where the best known area*time cost of breaking *at least one* of a set of $n$ target $k$-bit keys with nonnegligible probability is significantly less than $2^k$.  Using a 256-bit key for crypto_secretbox guarantees that even for an unimaginably large set of $2^{128}$ targets, the best known area*time cost of breaking at least one of those targets with nonnegligible probability still exceeds that of $2^{128}$ bit operations.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer !!! You really helped me out, as well as many other people who will read this discussion. One more thing: in my setup, within the Crypto Boxes is always contained a signed message (through another - sign - keypair and the sodium_crypto_sign function). This way Bob can prove to Charlie what message he got from Alice, right ? Is this a good/safe setup in your opinion ? Thanks again.

Comment: Not only does crypto_box not provide third-party-verifiable signature—it provides authentication _only_ to the recipient—but it's not even built out of a signature scheme: it uses a _symmetric_ authenticator under a _symmetric_ key shared using public-key key agreement between the sender and receiver.  (Contrast, _e.g._, S/MIME or OpenPGP, whose only authentication methods are built out of third-party-verifiable signatures.)  But if you _do_ want third-party-verifiable signatures, then you are right that crypto_sign provides that.

Answer (score 2):

Some of your assumption are closer, but not correctly at all. I think I can explain what is the X25519, XSalsa20 and the Poly1005.

The X25519 is the DH using the Curve25519, it has 128 bits of security, it allows to create some “shared-secret”, between both users involved.

The XSalsa20 is the symmetric encryption algorithm, that is uses the secret-key, that was “exchanged” in the X25519, and the nonce that you generate.

The Poly1305 is the MAC, it will guaranty that the message was not changed. To compare, if you use the OpenSSL before, with their AES-CBC, you probably use the HMAC, for the same reason. It’s not involved with the generation of the nonce.

---

Have something that is important to know. The Sealed Boxes(`sodium_crypto_box_seal`) and the Secret Boxes (`sodium_crypto_box`) are different. The “Sealed Boxes” uses a “temporary key” and the public key of the receiver, so the sender creates a random key for each message. The “Secret Boxes” uses the private key (and public key) of the sender and the public key of the recipient, so it allows to check who send it.

---

The assumption of 16^64 is correctly, since the key length is 256 bits. Until now, the brute force still the best attack method. But, as describe by @Squeamish Ossifrage, you need to generate a secure random key, in your post you mention about `sodium_crypto_box_keypair`, it is secure. The nonce need to be random and unique, you can use the `random_bytes(24)` for this propose, the length of the nonce is 24 bytes.

Comment: Thanks ! For clarity's sake: I am talking about Secret Boxes (not Sealed Boxes). Sorry for the confusion ... Hope someone can elaborate on how safe they are (cfr. brute force example I gave).

Comment: The secret key is 256 bits (or 32 bytes, or 64 hex digits), and there is no `crypto_box_secretkey` function. You might be confused with keys used for signatures.

Comment: @FrankDenis, Sorry for this mistake, that was not intentional, and thank you to report it. The `crypto_box_secretkey` exists in PHP, but it still using 256 bits, I will change it.

Comment: In PHP I would highly recommend using [Halite](https://github.com/paragonie/halite) instead of libsodium directly, as it provides a more idiomatic API.

Comment: @FrankDenis Is the underlying technology of Halite superior to the one of Libsodium, or does it only provide a "better" API ? Other differences/advantages ? Also: I read that Halite is a "dead" project (no new developments) while Libsodium is still releasing new versions. Is this true ? Many thanks !

Comment: It only provides a better API. That last updated happened 2 weeks ago, so it certainly isn't a dead project.

Comment: @FrankDenis Thanks again ... One more question: in my SODIUM_CRYPTO_BOX setup (in PHP), both parties (A and B) generate a random nonce through RANDOM_BYTES(SODIUM_CRYPTO_BOX_NONCEBYTES) at every message that is sent. My question is: does Libsodium automatically check whether a nonce has been used before ? Or do I have to check that in my code ? That is: if A sends a message to B using a nonce that has been used before (or if someone tries to do a replay attack), will B notice ? If yes: where does B store the previous nonces ? And until when does he store them (also after a reboot etc) ? Thx !!

Comment: The nonce is 192 bits. This is gigantic. If a random number generator is used to generate the nonces, the probability of having a collision is negligible. So, just use random_bytes() to generate your nonces.

Comment: @FrankDenis : OK, I get that and I know that it is extremely unlikely that using random_bytes identical nonces will be generated, but this question remains: if someone would intercept an encrypted msg (crypto box) from "Alice" and (without knowing the content) send the same encrypted msg to "Bob" (who already got this msg from Alice before and now gets it from the interceptor), will Libsodium's crypto_box_open at Bob's side detect the double use of the same none ? Or does Bob have to keep track of all previously used nonces (e.g. in his DB) and check all incoming nonces against that DB ?

Comment: It won't. See [Encrypting a sequence or a set of dependent messages](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/encrypted-messages.html) for more information. `crypto_box` is for independent messages. If you have a sequence of messages and want to detect duplicates, reordering, missing messages, use [`secretstream`](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/secretstream.html) instead (that the PHP bindings fully support). Or if you use `crypto_box`, the message you encrypt can contain a timetamp, a counter, etc.